# Pandas: How to change the format of output .csv data to use comma-delimiters?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, plotly, candlestick-chart

**Background**

Using `pandas`, the following program has been successfully used to resample millisecond-resolution tick data into 1 second interval OHLC (Open High Low Close) data. The tick data is read from a .csv file, and the program writes the 1 second OHLC data to a new .csv file with new column headers. The problem stems from the way the output data is formatted (tab-delimited instead of comma-delimited, and with undesirable column headers). This has made it challenging to plot OHLC candlestick charts using `plotly`. I have been opening the .csv file using Sublime Text 3.

**Goal:**

To 1) ensure the output OHLC (Open High Low Close) data is comma-delimited, and 2) to output the time only, without today's date. The desired format can be seen further below, beneath "*Desired output format of .csv*".

**Current attempt:**

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

# Read data from file
data_frame = pd.read_csv('input_data.csv',
                         names=['Date_time', 'Bid', 'Bid_qty', 'Ask', 'Ask_qty'],
                         index_col=0, parse_dates=True, delimiter = ',')
data_frame.head()

# Sample data at set intervals
data_bid=data_frame['Bid'].resample('1S').ohlc()
data_ask=data_frame['Ask'].resample('1S').ohlc()

data_bid.head()
data_ask.head()

# Concatenate bid and ask
data_ask_bid = pd.concat( 
    [data_bid, data_ask], axis=1,  
    keys=['Bid', 'Ask'])

# Display options
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None) # Display all rows
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) # Display all columns
pd.set_option('display.width', 150) # Fit columns on same line
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None) # Set max width

# Print to file
original_stdout = sys.stdout # Save reference to original standard output
with open('output_data.csv', 'w') as f:
    sys.stdout = f # Change the standard output
    print(data_ask_bid)
    sys.stdout = original_stdout # Reset standard output to original value
```

For the `pandas.read_csv` function, an attempt was made to use the argument `sep=','` which controls the delimiter character for the read_csv, but had no success. An attempt was also made to use the `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` function also with the argument `sep=','` when printing to the output file, which also was unsuccessful.

Input .csv data format (time, bid, bid quantity, ask, ask quantity):

```
00:00:00.033,10.6674,1000000,10.6724,1000000
00:00:00.060,10.6674,1000000,10.6724,2000000
00:00:01.645,10.6674,1000000,10.6724,1000000
00:00:01.670,10.6674,1000000,10.6724,2000000
00:00:02.198,10.6674,1000000,10.6724,1000000
00:00:03.198,10.6674,1000000,10.672,1000000
00:00:03.202,10.6671,1000000,10.672,1000000
00:00:03.202,10.6672,1000000,10.672,1000000
```

Current output format of .csv:

```
                         Bid                                 Ask                           
                        open     high      low    close     open     high      low    close
Date_time                                                                                  
2020-10-21 00:00:00  10.6674  10.6674  10.6674  10.6674  10.6724  10.6724  10.6724  10.6724
2020-10-21 00:00:01  10.6674  10.6674  10.6674  10.6674  10.6724  10.6724  10.6724  10.6724
2020-10-21 00:00:02  10.6674  10.6674  10.6674  10.6674  10.6724  10.6724  10.6724  10.6724
2020-10-21 00:00:03  10.6674  10.6674  10.6671  10.6672  10.6720  10.6720  10.6720  10.6720
```

**Desired output format of .csv:**

```
time,bid_open,bid_high,bid_low,bid_close,ask_open,ask_high,ask_low,ask_close
00:00:00,10.6674,10.6674,10.6674,10.6674,10.6724,10.6724,10.6724,10.6724
00:00:01,10.6674,10.6674,10.6674,10.6674,10.6724,10.6724,10.6724,10.6724
00:00:02,10.6674,10.6674,10.6674,10.6674,10.6724,10.6724,10.6724,10.6724
00:00:03,10.6674,10.6674,10.6671,10.6672,10.6720,10.6720,10.6720,10.6720
```

**Summary:**

Q1. How can each value (including the column headers) that is printed to the output .csv file be comma-delimited?

Q2. How can the time be shown **without today's date** in the output .csv file?

Comment: Pandas `to_csv()` defaults to comma separated values when it writes to file, and is the preferred method for doing so. Please show how you used it, and describe what exactly was wrong with the output?

Comment: Hi, the exact output can be seen above ("Current output format of .csv") where all values are delimited with what seem to be tabs. So that I can plot the data with `plotly` with ease, I would like each value to be delimited with a comma, as seen beneath the subheading "Desired output format of .csv".

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

From the docs, the default separator for pandas to_csv is comma. So you should get the file saved seperated by comma. Try opening the file in notepad or sublime or notepad++ or vi or emacs to check how the values are seperated

Comment: Thanks for the link- I have actually been opening the file in Sublime so I thought it was strange that the data didn't seem to be comma-delimited. I will edit my question to mention I have opened it with Sublime.

Comment: `data_ask_bid.to_csv('file.csv')` should indeed do what you want.

Comment: `An attempt was also made to use the pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` - nowhere in your example do you use `to_csv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to print the string representation of the dataframe to file, which is incorrect. If you do this it should work:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read data from file
data_frame = pd.read_csv('input_data.csv',
                         names=['Date_time', 'Bid', 'Bid_qty', 'Ask', 'Ask_qty'],
                         index_col=0, parse_dates=True, delimiter = ',')

# Sample data at set intervals
data_bid=data_frame['Bid'].resample('1S').ohlc()
data_ask=data_frame['Ask'].resample('1S').ohlc()

# Concatenate bid and ask
data_ask_bid = pd.concat( 
    [data_bid, data_ask], axis=1,  
    keys=['Bid', 'Ask'])

data_ask_bid.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: This is extremely close to what I am trying to achieve, so thank you. The header formats are slightly strange, however. The exact output of the first three rows is: ,Bid,Bid,Bid,Bid,Ask,Ask,Ask,Ask
,open,high,low,close,open,high,low,close
Date_time,,,,,,,, . But, the format of the time and price data itself is now as required.

Comment: You can manually change the column names by using: `data_ask_bid.columns = ['column1', 'column2', ...]` (before you do the `to_csv` call)